# How do I avoid syntax repitition when matching enums?

Tags: rust, enums, pattern-matching, match

I have a struct in which one of the fields is an enum, and when using a match statement there is a lot of repetition that feels avoidable.

Basically what I have now is

```
match self.foo // which is an enum, Foo {
    Foo::Bar => something,
    Foo::Bazz => something else,
    _ => you get the point

}
```

I tried:

```
match self.foo {
    Foo::{
       Bar => something,
       Bazz => something else,
    }
}
```

but did not have the intended effect. Is it possible to not have to retype Foo:: every time or is it just something I need to live with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can import the names of enum variants to use them directly:

```
use Foo::*;
match self.foo {
    Bar => something,
    Bazz => something else,
}
```

This is how `None` and `Some` work without needing `Option::` before them.

Comment: Can you constrain the scope of import to just within the `match` statement, or if you want to do that, you need to surround it all with a new scope?

Comment: @KevinAnderson You can only import in the surrounding scope.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `use Foo::*;` statement to bring all the variants of `Foo` into scope:

```
enum Foo {
    Bar,
    Bazz,
}

fn main() {
    let foo = Foo::Bar;
    
    use Foo::*;
    match foo {
        Bar => println!("something"),
        Bazz => println!("something else"),
    }
}
```